# Choosing numbers with replacement with maximum and minimum condition

Tags: probability

I encountered a question in probability today. It goes like

Three numbers are chosen at random, one after the other with replacement, from the set $S=\{1,2,3,...,100\}$. Let $p_1$ be the probability that the maximum of chosen numbers is at least 81 and $p_2$ be the probability that the minimum of chosen numbers is at most 40.

The value of $\frac{625}{4}p_1$ is...

The value of $\frac{125}{4}p_2$ is...

My approach is $p_1=1-$probability that maximum is less than 81$=1-(\frac{80}{100})^3=\frac{61}{125}$

and $p_2=$probability that minimum is atleast 40$=(\frac{60}{100})^3=\frac{27}{125}$

But I feel something is not right considering $\frac{625}{4}p_1$ and $\frac{125}{4}p_2$ and I am unable to figure out what it is. Please help?

Comment: see N.F. Taussig's answer.  the $\frac{625}{4}$ and $\frac{125}{4}$ factors are something of *red herrings*, meant to distract you.

Answer (score 2):

Your value for $p_1$ is correct.

There are $60$ numbers greater than $40$.  Hence, the probability that the minimum of the three chosen numbers is at most $40$ is
$$p_2 = 1 - \left(\frac{60}{100}\right)^3 = 1 - \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^3 = 1 - \frac{27}{125} = \frac{98}{125}$$
since the minimum will be at most $40$ unless all three selected numbers are among the $60$ numbers greater than $40$.